# terraformでAzureADに登録したアプリケーションの認証プラットフォームを追加できますか。

Tags: azure, terraform

terraformでAzureADにアプリを登録しました。
ソースは、下記の通りで`terraform apply`でアプリが登録されます。

```
$ cat app.tf
resource "azuread_application" "example" {
  name = "example"
}

resource "azuread_service_principal" "example" {
  application_id = azuread_application.example.application_id
}

resource "azuread_service_principal_password" "example" {
  service_principal_id = azuread_service_principal.example.id
  description          = "My managed password"
  value                = "VT=uSgbTanZhyz@%nL9Hpd+Tfay_MRV#"
  end_date             = "2099-01-01T01:02:03Z"
}

resource "azuread_application_password" "example" {
  application_object_id = azuread_application.example.id
  description           = "My managed password"
  value                 = "VT=uSgbTanZhyz@%nL9Hpd+Tfay_MRV#"
  end_date              = "2099-01-01T01:02:03Z"
}
```

アプリを登録したあとは、手動で、Azureのコンソールで登録したアプリの`認証`メニューから`プラットフォームの追加`を選択して、WebアプリやiOSなどのプラットフォームを選択して、コールバックURIを登録しています。

この手動の操作もterraformのtfファイルに設定したいと考えていますが、それらしいリソースがありません。

プラットフォームの追加をterraformで実現されている方はいますでしょうか。

Comment: AzureプロバイダのIssueに同じ内容のIssueがありました。
https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-azurerm/issues/5180

Comment: 下記に問い合せをしました。
https://discuss.hashicorp.com/t/is-it-possible-to-register-a-redirect-uri-in-terraforms-azuread-application-resource/16777

Answer (score 0):

下記のように`azuread_application`の`reply_urls`にコールバックURIを設定できました。

```
resource "azuread_application" "example" {
  name = "example"
  reply_urls = [
    "https://sample1.com/auth",
    "https://sample2.co.jp/auth"
  ]
}
```

[terraformのドキュメント](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azuread/latest/docs/resources/application#reply_urls)に、きちんと書いてありました。